# partial view inside partial view --- conditional

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, partial-views

I am porting a web forms application to MVC3

I have a partial view inside a partial view and the inner partial view is displayed on the basis of content from the model of the parent view.

The parent partial view has this model

```
@ModelType List(Of Integer)
```

and then these lines for adding multiple instances of a partial view in the same page.

```
<div style="width: 25%; vertical-align: bottom; float: left; clear: left">
    @Html.Partial("ArtBlock")
</div>
<div style="width: 25%; vertical-align: bottom; float: left; clear: left">
    @Html.Partial("ArtBlock")
</div>
<div style="width: 25%; vertical-align: bottom; float: left; clear: left">
    @Html.Partial("ArtBlock")
</div>
```

This div is repeated four times with four values of the `List(Of Integer)`. That is, if the first index contains a larger value than 100, it should display the first div above and so on...

**UPDATE:**
The inner partial controls are supposed to be accessed from the database on the basis of id from the index of the list.

I have created the functions in the DAL (which is a separate dll) and now only a function call remains.

In the web forms, the inner user controls were bound using the following...

```
ArtBlock1.Artikel = DataService.Artikel_GetByID(oList(0))
```

Can anybody help me on what to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent partial is typed `@ModelType List(Of Integer)` then iterate over the model to print out the divs. Something like this (excuse syntax errors if any, I use C#, looks like you are using VB)

```
@foreach(var value in Model)
{
    <div style="width: 25%; vertical-align: bottom; float: left; clear: left">
        @Html.Partial("ArtBlock", value)
    </div>
}
```

I believe you want to check the `value` so you can add an if in there.

**Update:**
So assuming your `DataService.Artikel_GetByID(oList(0))` returns an `Artikel`, your parent partial will be typed `@ModelType List(Of Artikel)`.
Use the same loop as above, but now your child partial is typed `@ModelType Artikel`.
Your partial action method would `return PartialView(artikelList, "nameOfPartial")`

Comment: Use a ViewModel that contains all of the necessary data. ViewModels are your friend.

Comment: How can the viewmodel contain such data, which is decided dynamically... I mean my ViewModel of view contains some data and then my ViewModel of Partial View contains some more data and then my ViewModel of inner Partial View contains some more data decided on run time.